# Can I pass App Builder transition exam without passing Winter16 Dev-401 release exam?

Tags: dev401, app-builder

I currently have Force.com developer certification (Summer15). I would like to pass to App builder transition exam (Winter16). do I have to pass the Winter16 of my current Dev-401 certification before attempting the transition exam?

The Dev-401 refresh costs 100$. The App Builder transition exam also costs 100$. Maybe I can directly jump to the transition exam and save 100$. Do you think that would be possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the release of the App Builder certification you'll obtain will be the same as the Developer certification you currently hold, so you'll need to sit the Winter'16 release exam anyway.

(I think that's correct, but can't check as I've already sat my Winter '16 release exams)